# pageref in glossary entry points to wrong page

Tags: glossaries

In the following MWE I have a `\pageref` in a glossary entry. It points to page 1 instead of to page 4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossary
\newglossaryentry{test}{name=test,description={this is a test (see page~\pageref{test})}}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-9]
\newpage This page has a glossary item with a link in it.
\label{test}\gls{test} but the link does not point to this page.
\newpage
\kant[10-11]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I tried to run latex latex makeglossaries latex latex makeglossaries latex, to no avail - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The link anchor is wrong, since there's no `\refstepcounter` which would provide the correct anchor. One solution is to use `\phantomsection\gls{test}\label{test}`

Comment: It seems a bit odd to suppress the location list and then add the location in the description. Perhaps it would be simpler just to show the location list? (You can override the `nonumberlist` option for individual entries.) If you want to limit the location list to a single page number, try [this sample file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/sample-altmodifier.tex).

Comment: I'm afraid I misled you with my MWE. The original doc has a term that needs an explanation, and the (short) explanation in the glosssary  points to a (different) page in the document where the term is fully explained.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense :-)